# Read signal level for ppp connection on RasPI

Tags: raspberry-pi3, at-command

I have a RasPI 3 with SIM800L connected via UART.

I use PPP connection to enable network traffic, and I want to get the signal level via AT command but device is busy when PPP is on.

Is it possibile to access to signal level? Or send a AT commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can suspend your PPP call using `+++` escape sequence. Something you need to know about the escape sequence:

1. **It doesn't end the PPP connection**; it just makes you control again AT UART while in the background it is mantained active
2. Before sending it, you must avoid sending characters for 1 second
3. The `+++` string needs to be sent with no further character in the middle within 1 second
4. After sending it, you must avoid sending characters for 1 second. Only then it will be interpreted as escape sequence (this is to avoid `+++` to be misinterpreted as data)

After you receive the `OK` response, you have AT interface back and you can send AT commands without dropping PPP connection, for example your `AT+CSQ` command to query  signal quality.
Of course it is better to avoid to stay too much in suspension, in order to avoid inactivity timeouts from the remote peer.

After you're done with the commands, you can restore data mode with `ATO`command.

Comment: Hi Roberto thanks for your suggestion and sorry for long delay. I've a problem to send second command. After ppp connection is open if I try to send a command (I try with minicom) the system replay with "Device or resource busy". How can I send it?

Comment: @andmattia you have to send escape sequence in the same port in which the ppp traffic occurs. Escape sequence is actually defined to go back temporarily to command mode

Comment: I think this is the problem. How can I send the command on same port? To start connection I use "sudo pon" so my SO open PPP connection and use UART port. After that if I try to open a minicom the connection is already in use. If I try to do the login sequence on mincom I cacth an error.